# Getting "missing ; before statement error in javascript

Tags: javascript

Only thing in the file is the following line:

```
@include Menu.js
```

Is there any way that it stops showing this error??

Comment: check where is ; is missing i think this will be after or before it.

Comment: Where does that include syntax come from? Never seen it in Javascript :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I assume `@include` is some server-side construct allowing you to include files.*

You must be having semi-colon missing in one or more statements of your Menu.js file. You can check that file at [JSHint.com](http://JSHint.com) about where that error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid JavaScript, not any of it, so of course you're going to see a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, I figure that qualifies this as being NARQ.